# web audio api: how to inspect the audio graph?

Tags: javascript, webkit, web-audio-api

The Web Audio Api [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#APIOverview-section) says:

> [...] AudioContext interface, which contains an audio signal graph
>   representing connections betweens AudioNodes.

I have a project with +/- 30 nodes connected nodes.
I am trying to write tests to check if the setup of the graph is correct. Therefore I need to inspect the resulting graph.
However, I have not been able to access/inspect the final graph, nor to find information on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually is no way to directly inspect the graph; you need to maintain your own pointers, etc. to inspect the graph.  This is partly to encourage/enable good garbage collection behavior.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Web Audio Inspector Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-audio-inspector/cmhomipkklckpomafalojobppmmidlgl).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Firefox has a Web Audio inspector that you can use for this. Enable it in your developer tools and you can get a graph of all the connected nodes. You can even modify the properties of nodes such as biquad filters.

[image]

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/06/introducing-the-web-audio-editor-in-firefox-developer-tools/

Comment: Sadly, this isn't a thing anymore.   :-/